# Ruby possible combination of array values - performance

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations

i need to quickly determine the possible uniq combinations of elements in an array based on a condition.

They have the following structure:

```
[[id,parent_id]]
```

I have no problems with smaller arrays. If all the parent_ids are uniq. Example:

```
a = (1..6).to_a.map{ |a| [a,a] }                                                
=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]]
a.combination(3).size # => 20
```

answers immediately.

If I have ids with reoccurring parent_ids I can still use combination and iterate through all combinations.

```
a = (1..7).to_a.map{ |a| [a,a] };a[6] = [7,6]
=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 6]]
a.combination(3).size # => 35
valid_combos = a.combination(3).to_a.select { |c| c.map(&:last).uniq.size == c.size }.size # => 30
```

This is still quick on small arrays. But if the arrays has 33 entries with 1 reoccurring parent_id I'll have to check 1166803110 combinations. This is slow. Of course.

Any ideas or hints on how to get this solved quickly and efficient are welcome.

I like the combination method for the Array class. But i would use a Hash or set too.

Also there could be arrays like:

```
 a = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 2], [7, 3], [8, 3]]
 a.combination(3).size #=> 56
```

But only 18 are "valid".

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Valid input no reoccurring parent_ids:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]
```

Valid output with combination of 4 each (5 uniq combos):

```
[[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]], [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5]], [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5]], [[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]], [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]]
```

Valid input 1 reoccurring parent_ids:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6,5]]
```

Valid output with combination of 4 each (9 uniq combos):

```
[[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]], [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5]], [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [6, 5]], [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5]], [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [6, 5]], [[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]], [[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4], [6, 5]], [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]], [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [6, 5]]]
```

These are the invalid combos [5,5] and [6,5] aren't allowed:

```
[[[1, 1], [2, 2], [5, 5], [6, 5]], [[1, 1], [3, 3], [5, 5], [6, 5]], [[1, 1], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 5]], [[2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5], [6, 5]], [[2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 5]], [[3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 5]]]
```

Comment: please provide valid input and output. Seems like you are looking for [permutations](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation) but I really can't tell as the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: The number of combinations you have to check is independent of how many parent_ids there are. With 33 array elements you only need to check [5456 combinations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=33C3) - not that many.

Comment: Despite my confusing explanation skills it breaks down the question: How do I perform efficient selects on very large arrays? I'm not looking for permutations.

Comment: @simonwo http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=33C16 and I have > 1 billion combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all possible combinations of ids where the ids don't share a parent id. I had a go at something different, just for fun, with no real idea if performance will improve.

```
x = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6,5]]
```

First, let's flip reduce it.

```
hash = x.reduce({}) {|hash, pair| (hash[pair.last] ||= []).push pair.first}
#=> {1=>[1], 2=>[2], 3=>[3], 4=>[4], 5=>[5, 6]}
```

Now we get all possible combinations of the parent IDs.

```
parents = hash.keys.combination(4).to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Now we map each parent ID to it's child ids.

```
children = parents.map do |array|
  array.map {|parent| hash[parent]}
end
#=>  [[[1], [2], [3], [4]], [[1], [2], [3], [5, 6]], [[1], [2], [4], [5, 6]], [[1], [3], [4], [5, 6]], [[2], [3], [4], [5, 6]]]
```

We're knee deep in arrays at this point. Now, we take the product of each sub-array to get all possible combinations, and we don't even need to uniq them.

```
children.map {|array| array.first.product *array.drop(1)}.flatten(1)
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Now you have all combinations of ids, and could use those to look up parent ids if you still need them using the opposite of the `hash` table.

What about performance? I benchmarked by running [this file](http://pastebin.com/CCgpRcxp).

With 50 entries, 25 repeated, and combination of 4:

```
3957124
Original:   8.719000   0.110000   8.829000 (  8.860909)
3957124
Simons:     4.875000   0.094000   4.969000 (  6.458309)
```

So it looks quicker in theory. But, with 125 entries, 25 repeated, and combination of 4:

```
9811174
Original:  22.875000   0.281000  23.156000 ( 23.213483)
9811174
Simons:    20.703000   0.391000  21.094000 ( 21.232167)
```

Which is not much faster. This is because for so many combinations Ruby spends the majority of it's time doing memory allocation (try watching in Task Manager or `top`), which in Ruby is *dog-slow*. There's not really any helpful way to allocate the memory up-front, so beyond a certain point you're at a hard limit.

But this is only happening because you're forcing Ruby to collect all of the array items together at once. If you're specific use case allows you to deal with each combination individually, you can avoid most of the memory allocation. By calling `yield` with every child array ([this file](http://pastebin.com/9suKFeQg)):

```
9811174
Simons:    8.485000   0.000000   8.485000 (  8.476653)
```

Much quicker. You will also observe the memory usage remains constant. [It's still gonna take a while though](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2833+choose+16%29+%2F+%28125+choose+4%29+*+8+seconds). However, if you have multiple cores you could in principle parallelise because once you have the hash each combination can be worked on independently of the others. I'll leave that for you to try :)

Comment: I think we did much the same in our respective answers, but that's probably unavoidable. Feel free to add my method to your benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that as follows.

**Code**

```
def combos(pairs, group_size)
  pairs.group_by(&:last).
        values.
        combination(group_size).
        flat_map { |a| a.shift.product(*a) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
pairs = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6,5]]

combos(pairs, 4)
   #=> [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]],
   #    [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5]],
   #    [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [6, 5]],
   #    [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5]],
   #    [[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [6, 5]],
   #    [[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]],
   #    [[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4], [6, 5]],
   #    [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]],
   #    [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [6, 5]]] 
 combos(pairs, 5)
   #=>  [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]],
   #     [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [6, 5]]] 

 combos(pairs, 1).size #=>  6 
 combos(pairs, 2).size #=> 14 
 combos(pairs, 3).size #=> 16 
 combos(pairs, 4).size #=>  9 
 combos(pairs, 5).size #=>  2
```

**Explanation**

For the array `pairs` used in the examples, and

```
group_size = 4
```

we perform the following calculations. First we group the elements of pairs by the last element of each pair (i.e., `parent_id`):

```
h = pairs.group_by(&:last)
  #=> {1=>[[1, 1]], 2=>[[2, 2]], 3=>[[3, 3]], 4=>[[4, 4]], 5=>[[5, 5], [6, 5]]}
```

We only need the values from this hash:

```
b = h.values
  #=> [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]], [[5, 5], [6, 5]]]
```

We now obtain combinations of the elements of `b`:

```
enum = b.combination(group_size)
  #=> b.combination(4)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]],
  #                  [[5, 5], [6, 5]]]:combination(4)>
```

We can view the (5) elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]]],
  #    [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[5, 5], [6, 5]]],
  #    [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[4, 4]], [[5, 5], [6, 5]]],
  #    [[[1, 1]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]], [[5, 5], [6, 5]]],
  #    [[[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]], [[5, 5], [6, 5]]]]
```

The last step is to map each element of `enum` to the product of its elements (each element of `enum` being an array of pairs). We use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) so we don't have to subsequently do any flattening:

```
enum.flat_map { |a| a.shift.product(*a) }
```

returns the array given in the examples for `group_size = 4`.

Let's look more carefully as what is happening in the last statement:

```
enum1 = enum.flat_map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]],
  #                     [[5, 5], [6, 5]]]:combination(4)>:flat_map>
```

You might want to think of `enum1` as a "compound enumerator". The elements of `enum1` are passed into it's block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) (which will call [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)) and assigned to the block variable `a`. Let's look at the second value passed to the block.

Skip the first:

```
a = enum1.next
  #=> [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[4, 4]]]
```

Pass in the second:

```
a = enum1.next
  #=> [[[1, 1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3]], [[5, 5], [6, 5]]]
```

We take the product of these four arrays as follows:

```
a[0].product(a[1], a[2], a[3])
  #=> [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5]],
  #    [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [6, 5]]]
```

which we could also write:

```
a[0].product(*a[1..-1])
```

or, as I have done:

```
a.shift.product(*a)
```

Note that, in the last expression, `a` of `*a` is what's left of `a` after `a.shift` is executed.